# Showing Android "direct share" targets for a logged-out app

Tags: android, sharing

With Android's *direct share* feature, is it ok to show share targets for an app that is in a logged-out state?

Pro: It helps users discover your app and when they tap on the target, it will simply launch the app and show login page.

Con: Users from the app are visible as direct share targets even though the app is logged out. Could that be a privacy issue?

Answer (score 1):

I don't find this as a privacy issue as the user already agreed to log in . On the ground of showing apps (logged out state) in direct share is good until the app is a sharing medium / a community (e.g message WhatsApp. FB etc) rather than a tool ( calculator, camera etc). It shows the intelligence of the machine identifying all possible sharing medium in the device.